# How Do I Add a Parallax Effect To A UITableView Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, parallax, uimotioneffect

Hello I am creating a sort of social media app and I am using table view to display all the information, I have made a parallax effect and at first it works nicely and smoothly, but after couple of times of moving my device it becomes supper jittery and way to quick

Here is the extension that I have created that I am adding to my TableViewCellView: (I call it like this: myCell.addParallax(magnitude: 10) )

```
extension UIView {
func addParallax(magnitude: Float) {
    let xMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.x", type: .tiltAlongHorizontalAxis)
    xMotion.maximumRelativeValue = magnitude
    xMotion.minimumRelativeValue = -magnitude

    let yMotion = UIInterpolatingMotionEffect(keyPath: "center.y", type: .tiltAlongVerticalAxis)
    yMotion.maximumRelativeValue = magnitude
    yMotion.minimumRelativeValue = -magnitude

    let motionEffect = UIMotionEffectGroup()
    motionEffect.motionEffects = [xMotion, yMotion]
    self.addMotionEffect(motionEffect)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableViewCell`s are being reused while the table is scrolled by the user. In the `cellForRow atIndexPath` method you're most likely using `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` method. This method doesn't create new cells all the time, it reuses the ones that are not visible anymore.

The `UIMotionEffectGroup` you're creating is being added to the `UITableViewCell` each time the `myCell.addParallax(magnitude: 10)` is called. In the end, you're having many `UIMotionEffectGroup` which is the source of your problem. Make sure that this method is called only once per cell, you can use `awakeFromNib` method in the cell itself to achieve this.